# How to achieve this logic of 'summing up values of map keys inside a list'

Tags: flutter, dart

- I have a list of Map<String, int>, let's call it salesData.
- Each element inside this list represents a sale.
- Each sale may have products that may or may not exist in other sales.

**Note:** this data comes from some api, therefore the products' name aren't known!

```
    List<Map<String, int>> salesData = [
    {'product A': 12, 'product B': 30, 'product C': 17, 'product K': 220},
    {'product A': 3, 'product F': 2, 'product C': 10},
    {'product F': 6, 'product S': 4, 'product A': 1},
    {'product F': 1, 'product S': 11,},
  ];
```

**My goal is to get an instance of each product and the summed up totals from all the sales.**
for example the totals of product A is 16, B is 30, so on.

**Things I have tried:**

```
Map<String, int> finalSaleData = {};

Set<String> mySet = {};

for (var element in salesData) {
      mySet.addAll(element.keys);
    }

for (var productName in mySet) {
    finalSaleData[productName] = salesData.fold(0, (previousValue, e) => previousValue + e[element]); 
   // this line works as long as the e[element] exists, but not if it doesn't!
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final result = salesData.reduce((sum, item) =>
  {...sum, ...item.map((key, value) =>
    MapEntry(key, (sum[key] ?? 0) + value)
  )}
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly. Could you please explain to me what the triple dots mean?

Comment: Take a look on [Spread Collections](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/spread-collections/feature-specification.md).

Answer (score 2):

```
Map summingItUp = Map();
for (Map item in salesData) {
  item.forEach((key, value) {
    if (summingItUp.containsKey(key))
      summingItUp[key] = summingItUp[key] + value;
    else
      summingItUp[key] = value;
  });
}
print(summingItUp);
```

the result would be:

```
{product A: 16, product B: 30, product C: 27, product K: 220, product F: 9, product S: 15}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I wanted.